# Pandas dataframe - running sum within cluster

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumulative-sum

I have

```
    x  cluster_id
0   1      1
1   3      1
2   2      2
3   5      2
4   4      3
```

I want to generate

```
    x  cluster_id   s
0   1      1        1
1   3      1        4
2   2      2        3
3   5      2        7
4   4      3        4
```

i.e. `s` is the running sum of `x`, but it gets reset when the cluster id changes. How is this achieved?

Alternatively, if it is easier, it may be Ok to do

```
    x  cluster_id   s
0   1      1        4
1   3      1        4
2   2      2        7
3   5      2        7
4   4      3        4
```

i.e. all values for `s` within the same cluster are the same, and correspond to the total sum in the cluster.

Additionally, I want to subsample this so that I keep the last row of each cluster:

```
    x  cluster_id   s
1   3      1        4
3   5      2        7
4   4      3        4
```

(note that all the cluster ids are different). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the running totals using `.cumsum()` with `.groupby()`

```
>>> df
   x  cluster_id
0  1           1
1  3           1
2  2           2
3  5           2
4  4           3
>>> df['s'] = df.groupby('cluster_id').cumsum()
>>> df
   x  cluster_id  s
0  1           1  1
1  3           1  4
2  2           2  2
3  5           2  7
4  4           3  4
```

Then to get only the last row for each `cluster_id`:

```
>>> df.groupby('cluster_id').last().reset_index()
   cluster_id  x  s
0           1  3  4
1           2  5  7
2           3  4  4
```

Comment: How about the subsampling part?

Comment: Ah I missed that the first time round. I just edited the answer to include subsampling.

Comment: Cool, I will accept in a minute. Btw, why I need the reset_index() part?

Comment: Without `.reset_index()` the `.groupby()` will use the grouped values (`cluster_id` in this case) for the index.